# mysql select records based on the value of another field

Tags: mysql

I want to get some records from a single table based on the value from a single record;

Here is my `replaces`table showing some test records

```
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
| ProductID | order | replacement | group |
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
|    1      |  30   |     35      |   1   |
|    1      |  30   |     40      |   1   |
|    1      |  35   |     30      |   1   |
|    1      |  35   |     40      |   1   |
|    1      |  40   |     30      |   1   |
|    1      |  40   |     35      |   1   |
+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
```

UNIQUE KEY `index` (`ProductID`(10),`order`,`replacement`)

What I want to get is that if I am currently working on order #30 I want to know that either 35 or 40 can be used as a replacement. After looking at another answer on here this is what I cam up with;

```
SELECT replacement FROM replaces r1 WHERE `ProductID` = '1' AND r1.group = ( SELECT group FROM replaces r2 WHERE order.r1 = 30 )
```

I've tried moving things around and referencing the fields in different ways but I always get syntax errors.

Comment: What is replaces r1    and replaces r2   ..... isn't just one table?

Comment: Is the table named `replacement` or `replaces`? And where is the `group` column in the table?

Comment: Yes, the statement and the table have nothing in COMMON lol

Comment: Yeah, table name was wrong. Sorry, it's `replaces`. Bad question posting, that are all group 1.

Comment: You have two tables and you are trying retrieve data from replaqces1 based on the value of order(replaces2)......OR its just one table

Comment: Just one table. The answer that I saw they were using two different references like r1 and r2. You can see I don't get this.

Comment: No one table can only have one ALias  example table1 t1

Comment: Try : SELECT replacement 
FROM replaces  
WHERE `ProductID` = '1' AND order= 30;

Comment: You dont need Aliases since they are confusing you more . just table name ...... Also what is the condition for GROUP= ??

Comment: You are right. I don't know why I thought this was more complicated than it was. Your simple answer was all I needed. Some times I over complicate these queries. Thx

Answer (score 0):

`=` can only be used to compare with a single value. If the subquery can return multiple rows, you have to use `IN`:

```
SELECT replacement 
FROM replaces r1 
WHERE `ProductID` = '1' 
AND r1.group IN ( SELECT group FROM replaces r2 WHERE r2.order = 30 )
```

You also had an incorrect `WHERE` clause in the subquery.

or write a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT r1.replacement
FROM replaces r1
JOIN replaces r2 ON r1.group = r2.group
WHERE r1.productID = '1'
AND r2.order = 30
```

This answer needs more work, I think the original question has mistakes. Answer my question in the above comments.

Comment: Your second answer returned 11 rows. I fixed the question though.

Comment: I don't see how to fix my answer yet. Everything has the same `group`, so they'll all be matched. Are you sure that's the column you want to compare between the main query and the subquery?